# Haskell Linear Algebra Matrix Library for Arbitrary Element Types

Tags: haskell, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm looking for a Haskell linear algebra library that has the following features:

- Matrix multiplication
- Matrix addition
- Matrix transposition
- Rank calculation
- Matrix inversion is a plus

and has the following properties:

- arbitrary element (scalar) types (in particular element types that are *not* `Storable` instances). My elements are an instance of `Num`, additionally the multiplicative inverse can be calculated. The elements mathematically form a finite field (<sub>2<sup>256</sup></sub>). That should be enough to implement the features mentioned above.
- arbitrary matrix sizes (I'll probably need something like *100x100*, but the matrix sizes will depend on the user's input so it should not be limited by anything else but the memory or the computational power available)
- as fast as possible, but I'm aware that a library for arbitrary elements will probably not perform like a C/Fortran library that does the work (interfaced via FFI) because of the indirection of arbitrary (non `Int`, `Double` or similar) types. At least one pointer gets dereferenced when an element is touched
- (written in Haskell, this is not a real requirement for me, but since my elements are no `Storable` instances the library has to be written in Haskell)

I already tried very hard and evaluated everything that looked promising (most of the libraries on Hackage directly state that they wont work for me). In particular I wrote test code using:

- [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.14.1.0), assumes `Storable` elements
- [Vec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Vec), but the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Vec/1.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vec.html) states:

> Low Dimension : Although the dimensionality is limited only by what GHC will handle, the library is meant for 2,3 and 4 dimensions. For general linear algebra, check out the excellent hmatrix library and blas bindings
>   
>   I looked into the code and the documentation of many more libraries but nothing seems to suit my needs :-(.

#### Update

Since there seems to be nothing, I started a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/weissi/matrix-arbitrary) which aims to develop such a library. The current state is *very* minimalistic, not optimized for speed at all and only the most basic functions have tests and therefore should work. But should you be interested in using or helping out developing it: Contact me (you'll find my mail address on my [web site](http://tux4u.de)) or send pull requests.

Comment: `Storable` is elementary to the FFI, allowing values to be marshalled in to a form the interfaced code can read.  Without that caveat, I imagine the work would need to be done entirely within Haskell.

Comment: Yes, I know. And yes, I'm searching for a library entirely written in Haskell. Put that in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the code for `Vec`, I think that the *Low Dimension* caveat is purely there because of the inefficiency of it running in Haskell only without using auxiliary compiled libraries.  Hence the recommendation to use `hmatrix`. :-/

Comment: Hasn't `Vec` one type for each possible matrix size? It has e.g. `Matrix33` which is a *3x3* matrix. To support *100x100* matrices, GHC had to generate a lot of types. And: I think I need a library without static matrix size checking because I don't know the matrix sizes at compile time!

Comment: Aye, sounds like you might have an opening for a new library.

Comment: Hehe, I'll probably need to... I'm currently writing my diploma thesis (Master's thesis equivalent in Germany) in computer science/cryptography and I already had to write the finite field library. In fact, I interfaced a C++ library. Don't know if I have the time to additionally implement such an matrix library. I'll see...

Comment: Hopefully somebody will come up with an existing library.  I wonder if LAPACK could handle your data, if a suitable interface was devised to make your data Storable...  I remember doing my master's thesis a decade ago, I'm sure you do not need this stress! lol

Comment: LAPACK and even FFPACK/FFLAS do not even work with scalar elememts of the field I'm using (GF(2^256)). There are very few libraries for such large finite fields. With linear algebra algorithms it looks even worse. Therefore I'm looking for a generic lin alg library...

Comment: I was looking for something like this a couple of months ago. If you end up developing something I would be interested in helping out (email in profile).

Comment: @ChrisTaylor , that's cool, thanks :-). I will let you know as soon as I really start implementing such a library.

Answer (score -2):

well, I'm note really sure how much relevant my answer is but Im having good experiences with GNU GSL library and there is a wrapper for haskel:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-gsl

Check it out, maybe it will help you

Comment: GSL does not support arbitrary elements. It works on `Double`s